# Async/Await and Caching

Tags: c#, caching, async-await

My service layer is caching alot of Db requests to memcached, does this make it impossible to use Async/Await?? For example how could I await this?

```
public virtual Store GetStoreByUsername(string username)
{
        return _cacheManager.Get(string.Format("Cache_Key_{0}", username), () =>
        {
                return _storeRepository.GetSingle(x => x.UserName == username);
        });
}
```

Note: If the key exists in the cache it will return a "Store" (not a `Task<Store>`), if the key does not exist in the cache it will execute the lambda. If I change the Func to

```
return await _storeRepository.GetSingleAsync(x => x.UserName == username);
```

And the method signature to

```
public virtual async Task<Store> GetStoreByUsername(string username)
```

This will not work obviously because of the cache return type.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like the cache-manager does all the "check it exists, if not run the lambda then store". If so, the only way to make that `async` is to have a `GetAsync` method that returns a `Task<Store>` rather than a `Store`, i.e.

```
public virtual Task<Store> GetStoreByUsernameAsync(string username)
{
    return _cacheManager.GetAsync(string.Format("Cache_Key_{0}", username), () =>
    {
        return _storeRepository.GetSingleAsync(x => x.UserName == username);
    });
}
```

Note that this doesn't need to be marked `async` as we aren't using `await`. The cache-manager would then do something like:

```
public async Task<Store> GetAsync(string key, Func<Task<Store>> func)
{
    var val = cache.Get(key);
    if(val == null)
    {
        val = await func().ConfigureAwait(false);
        cache.Set(key, val);
    }
    return val;
}
```

Comment: Nitpicking: `return val.Result`. Also, perhaps `Task.FromResult` is redundant: `var val = func(); await val.ConfigureAwait(false);  cache.Set(key, val);`

Comment: @Noseratio yeah, sorry, brain wasn't working; better?

Comment: It still won't compile :) You're storing the result, not the task.

Comment: @Noseratio yes, with the edit that is intentional, and it compiles fine

Comment: How would you do this if you wanted to make it threadsafe? I tried to add a lock, however you can't put a lock around an await.

Comment: @Ryan indeed you can't; do you have an example where you would want to?

Comment: It's worth noting that the cache object in GetAsync should be thread-safe. For example, if GetStoreByUsernameAsync was called in a loop with the same username, the continuations adding the value to the cache and the original thread calling cache.get() could all be running on different threads.

Comment: Also, this method wouldn't guarantee no cache misses for the same username. Same example as above - loop with same username. The DB request could be made many times before the first response was returned and cached, at which point the cache would start getting used. See my answer for a possible solution to this.

Answer (score 24):

Here's a way to cache results of asynchronous operations that guarantees no cache misses and is thread-safe.

In the accepted answer, if the same username is requested many times in a loop or from multiple threads the DB request will keep getting sent until there's a response that gets cached, at which point the cache will start getting used.

The method below creates a [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim(v=vs.110).aspx) object for each unique key. This will prevent the long running `async` operation from running multiple times for the same key while allowing it to be running simultaneously for different keys. Obviously, there's overhead keeping `SemaphoreSlim` objects around to prevent cache misses so it may not be worth it depending on the use case. But if guaranteeing no cache misses is important then this accomplishes that.

```
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, SemaphoreSlim> _keyLocks = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, SemaphoreSlim>();
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Store> _cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Store>();

public async Task<Store> GetStoreByUsernameAsync(string username)
{   
    Store value;
    // get the semaphore specific to this username
    var keyLock = _keyLocks.GetOrAdd(username, x => new SemaphoreSlim(1));
    await keyLock.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    try
    {
        // try to get Store from cache
        if (!_cache.TryGetValue(username, out value))
        {
            // if value isn't cached, get it from the DB asynchronously
            value = await _storeRepository.GetSingleAsync(x => x.UserName == username).ConfigureAwait(false);

            // cache value
            _cache.TryAdd(username, value);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        keyLock.Release();
    }
    return value;
}
```

Note: To further optimize this method, an additional cache check could be performed before the lock acquisition step.

Comment: Any particular reason, why you just didn't use a `ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>` and `lock(obj) {...}` instead of `SemaphoreSlim`? I did some benchmarking and `locks` seem to be faster in my case

Comment: I used `SemaphoreSlim` because it offers an async wait method. And you're not able to `await` inside the body of a lock statement.

Comment: But please be aware that it'll eat up memory because neither keys nor semaphore will be GC'ed, the `_keyLocks` will keep the references

Comment: Yes, to clear the cache you'd have to clear both `_keyLocks` and `_cache`.